# Importing difference in python3.6 and python3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question about imports in python3.6 and python3.7.

I have the following dir structure:

```
.
└── lib
    ├── feature
    │   ├── feature1.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── new
    │       ├── feature1.py
    │       └── __init__.py
    └── __init__.py
```

I have the following in the file `lib/feature/__init__.py`:

```
from lib.feature.feature1 import Feature1
```

I have the following in the file `lib/feature/feature1.py`:

```py
import lib.feature.new.feature1 as new

class Feature1: pass
```

To recreate my environment, you can use the following:

```
mkdir lib
touch lib/__init__.py
mkdir -p lib/feature/new
echo "from lib.feature.feature1 import Feature1" > lib/feature/__init__.py
echo -e "import lib.feature.new.feature1 as new\nclass Feature1: pass" > lib/feature/feature1.py
touch lib/feature/new/__init__.py
touch lib/feature/new/feature1.py
```

When I run this code with python3.7 it works perfectly fine. When I run this code with python3.6, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "***/import_test/lib/feature/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from lib.feature.feature1 import Feature1
  File "***/import_test/lib/feature/feature1.py", line 2, in <module>
    import lib.feature.new.feature1 as new
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'feature'
```

So my question is, why is there a different outcome, when you run the code with python3.6 or python3.7?

To fix this issue, I have change the import in `lib/feature/feature1.py` to:

```py
from .new import feature1 as new
```

To test, I just go to python and try to import the module:

```
import_test$ python
Python 3.6.8 (default, Dec 25 2018, 00:00:00)
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lib.feature
```

After that change, it works on python3.6 as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please also show us how do you run the code with the 2 *Python* versions.

Comment: Using a modules classes before the module has been initialised doesn't sound like a  very good thing to do anyway, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @CristiFati I just go to python and I am using the following command for testing: ```import lib.feature```

Comment: @Bajo: you missed the command. Maybe you should paste that info (the commands and the prompt) in the question.

Comment: @Sayse I have more features, and more underlaying options for each feature. Then I select the appropriate functions for each feature, based on initialisation parameters...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a [bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue23203) with "aliasing" imports (`import .. as`) that got fixed in Python 3.7.